# MouseListener doesn't appear to be working for me

Tags: java

I need to preface this with my instructor doesn't let us use IDE's. We use TextPad. I want to click on this label and it then change from "H" to "T". Currently when I click the label does nothing. What am I forgetting?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Lab3Label extends JLabel implements MouseListener {
    int count = 0;
    boolean flag = true;

    public Lab3Label (int i) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        count = i;
        this.setText("H");
        this.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 60));
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {

            if(flag){
                this.setText("H");
                flag = false;
            }

            else{
                this.setText("T");
                flag = true;
            }
        }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}


}
```

Comment: "my instructor doesn't let us use IDE's" *groan*

Comment: Tell me about it. When I graduate I am gonna have to learn how to use eclipse/netbeans from scratch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `JLabel` implements `MouseListener`, but you also need to tell the `JLabel` to send events to itself. At the end of the constructor you'll need to say

```
addMouseListener(this);
```

This makes more sense if you remember that you can make *any* class into a `MouseListener`, and you'd have to connect your listener to your `JLabel`. The fact that the `JLabel` is its own listener doesn't absolve you of this responsibility.

Comment: Crap I saw that in the last lab I did and still forgot to put it. Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to get a random True / false everytime I click?

Comment: Sure, you could test if `java.lang.Math.random()` was less than 0.5; that'll be true about half the time.

Answer (score 2):

You never added the MouseListener to your label.

To do this, simply add the following code:

```
    addMouseListener(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you need to add the mouse listener to your JLabel. In your constructor add:

```
addMouseListener(this);
```